# Node Package karma not running with no info

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I created the karma.conf.js file to run tests but it is not working and terminal returns no useful info. there is nothing about my document where the error could be provoked, no line number... I've been looking through the file since 2 days and can't find what the reason could be.

This is terminal answer:

```
$ karma start karma.conf.js
12 04 2016 16:08:09.101:ERROR [config]: Invalid config file!
  SyntaxError: Unexpected string
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.parseConfig (/Users/Bizarre/Desktop/Coding/Web/UHK/Course3/conFusion/node_modules/karma/lib/config.js:284:22)
    at new Server (/Users/Bizarre/Desktop/Coding/Web/UHK/Course3/conFusion/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:57:20)
    at Object.exports.run (/Users/Bizarre/Desktop/Coding/Web/UHK/Course3/conFusion/node_modules/karma/lib/cli.js:243:7)
    at requireCliAndRun (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-cli/bin/karma:44:16)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-cli/bin/karma:54:12
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:44:21
    at ondir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:187:31)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:153:39
    at onex (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:93:22)
```

This is the karma.conf.js file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: '../',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
            'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
            'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'app/scripts/*.js'
            'test/unit/**/*.js'
        ],

    // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [
            'test/protractor.conf.js', 'test/e2e/*.js'
        ],

    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
        preprocessors: {

        },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
        reporters: ['progress'],

    // web server port  
        port: 9876,

    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true, 

    // level of logging 
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO, 

    // enable / disable watching file and executing any file changes
        autoWatch: true, 

    // start these browsers
    //available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
        browsers: ['Chrome','PhantomJS','PhantomJS_custom'],

    // you can define custom flags
        customLaunchers: {
            'PhantomJS_custom': {
                base: 'PhantomJS',
                options: {
                    windowName: 'my-window',
                    settings: {
                        webSecurityEnabled: false
                    },
                },
                flags: ['--load-images=true'],
                debug: true
            }
        },

        phantomjsLauncher: {
            // Have phantomjs exit if a ResourceError is encountered (useful if karma exits without killing phantom) 
            exitOnResourceError: true
        },

        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        singleRun: false,

        // Concurrency level
        // how many browser should be started simultaneously
        concurrency: Infinity

    })
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a comma missing in files:

```
 // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
            'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
            'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'app/scripts/*.js',
            'test/unit/**/*.js'
        ]
```

,

Comment: thanks! can't believe I didn't see it! Also makes no sense that terminal gives no clue where the "unexpected string" is